# Not all java buttons are following look and feel

Tags: java, macos, user-interface

Okay.  So I've noticed that only the first JFrame that loads, utilizes the LookAndFeel fully.  I have a mac, so the buttons should be rounded and smooth.  The first JFrame that loads, is a login.  The button on this frame is correct.  If you login, the buttons on the main panel page have the window look and feel of OSX but the buttons do not.

I have the look and feel being set like:

```
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

in the StartUp. Which is the class that contains the main() method.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`

if you want to have the OS X look and feel. The "cross platform look and feel" is the one that looks equal on all platforms (OS X, Windows, Linux).

To set the "correct" look and feel for the platform, you should call

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

as early as possible, before any other GUI code.

Comment: But I want it to display like a windows application if it's windows, or display like a mac application if it's mac.

Comment: `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` will return the correct look and feel for each platform.

Comment: That did work.  I'm sorry I misread it and it appeared to be the same thing at first.  Thank you for your help!